# How to check if Unicode symbol in Form D originated from angstrom sign?

Tags: c#, macos, unicode, xamarin.mac, .net-4.8

I need to compare path to file on Mac (represented as Unicode string in normal form D) with other path stored in a variable (can be any Unicode string, probably not normalized).

The problem is that there are different Unicode symbols that have similar representation in Form D. For example an Angstrom Sign (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+212B) and Latin A with Ring (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00C5) are both represented by A (U+0041) plus ◌̊ (U+030A).

Currently I make the comparison by first normalizing both strings. But then I am not able to distinguish Latin A from Angstrom, while this difference is important as we are talking about paths in file system.

So the question is - What is the right way to compare Unicode strings and not confuse such symbols?

P.S. Symbols like Angsrom sign are called Unicode Singletones. I would like to see full list of such symbols but cannot find it. I will be grateful if someone gives me a link.

Comment: There is the normalization form KD. The "Normalization form D" is for canonical equivalence (so semantically the same. But units are semantically different so you need the KD (compatibility). K forms are used for searches (but 2 and ² are K equivalent, so sometime they may get too broad). OTOH Latin A, and Greek A are the same glyph, but never normalized equal (there are other tables for that)

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi I tried to convert these symbols into form KD and they both become A [65] ̊ [778] (same representation as in Form D). So it doesn't help to distinguish them - am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. I was wrong. 212B must be handled as equivalent to 00C5, so there is no way to distinguish it. It is not a compatibility issue. So no, by applying any compatibility you lose information

Comment: "However, they are not injective (they map different original glyphs and sequences to the same normalized sequence) and thus also not bijective (**can't be restored**). For example, the distinct Unicode strings "U+212B" (the angstrom sign "Å") and "U+00C5" (the Swedish letter "Å")" (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

Comment: Certain characters are known as [singletons](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Singletons_Figure). They never remain in the text after normalization. Examples include the angstrom and ohm symbols, which map to their normal letter counterparts a-with-ring and omega, respectively. See _Singleton equivalence_ in [Canonical and Compatibility Equivalence](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence) as well.